How to use numpy polynomial expression without numpy?
To follow up on a previous question, I would like to extract the polynomial to calculate the result for certain values ​​in a python environment without numpy.
The code :
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
x = [430, 518, 471, 581, 330, 560, 387, 280, 231, 196, 168, 148, 136, 124, 112, 104, 101, 93, 88, 84, 80, 76]
y = [13, 10.5, 11.5, 10, 16.9, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90]

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
polynomial = Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg=7)
x1 = np.arange(76, 570, 1)
y1 = [polynomial(i) for i in x1]
plt.plot(x1, y1, '-')
print("polynomial result :")
print(polynomial)
print("-------------------")

# test single value of x
x2 = 330
y2_direct = 16.94343988 - 11.3117263*x2 + 17.65987276*x2**2 - 31.01304843*x2**3 - 21.01641368*x2**4 + 46.31228129*x2**5 + 36.3575357*x2**6 - 44.05000699*x2**7
y2_poly = polynomial(x2)
print("y2_direct = ", y2_direct)
print("y2_poly = ", y2_poly)

plt.legend('data deg7'.split())
plt.show()

I get this :


Why the 2 values ​​y2_direct and y2_poly are different?

Why are you doing a polyfit at all? This looks like it could be a hyperbolum or exponential decay.

Honestly, it's been too long since I did this type of math exercise... I did what I could with what I found on the Internet...

The string representation of the polynomial printed to the console is incomplete. If you display it (e.g. on Colab), it indicates that your data needs to be shifted and scaled to the "window" [-1, 1] before evaluating the polynomial:
x2 = 330
x2 = -1.3009901 + 0.0039694*x2  # shift and scale data to "window" [-1, 1]

16.94343988 - 11.3117263*x2 + 17.65987276*x2**2 - 31.01304843*x2**3 - 21.01641368*x2**4 + 46.31228129*x2**5 + 36.3575357*x2**6 - 44.05000699*x2**7
# 16.84401140712287

The documentation refers to this shifting and scaling as a "linear map" between the "domain" and "window" [-1, 1]. You can get the parameters of the map programmatically like:
polynomial.mapparms()
# (-1.300990099009901, 0.0039603960396039604)


Thanks Matt, I clearly didn't understand these notions of shift and scale to apply.
